# udev rules for video devices

Tags: udev

good day everyone.
there is a problem with creating symlink for video device after reboot.
i've got 2 video devices webcam and pci tvtuner. i've wrote rules conf
like this

```
SUBSYSTEM=="video4linux", ATTRS{idVendor}=="5986", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0105", GROUP="video",SYMLINK+="webcam0"
SUBSYSTEM=="video4linux", ATTRS{vendor}=="0x1131", ATTRS{device}=="0x7134", GROUP="video", SYMLINK+="beholder0"
```

then when i reboot the system symlink for webcam is created but for the tuner doesn't and when i test the rule conf with

```
udevadm test /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:01:06.0/video4linux/video1
```

symlink for tuner is creating. 
where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by rewriting the rule for the tuner like this:

```
KERNEL=="video*",ATTRS{vendor}=="0x1131", ATTRS{device}=="0x7134", GROUP="video", SYMLINK+="beholder0"
```